# Altering Fake Columns based on Query Values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query and change fake column values based on whether the internal queries return anything.

Basically I want the below code to be able to change WI to a 1 if id is in table2 and SI to 1 if id is in table3

```
SELECT name, grade, id, 0 as WI, 0 as SI FROM students
WHERE id in table1
AND (id in table2
OR id in table3)
```

I've been googling around but haven't run across anything, I think mostly because I don't know what the "fake" columns are actually called.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Edit:
Data looks something like this:

```
name  grade  id
s1    1      0
s2    1      1
s3    2      7
```

and the goal would be to have something like this come out after the query:

```
name  grade  id  WI  SI
s1    1      0   0   1
s2    1      1   1   1
s3    2      7   1   0
```

EDIT 2:
Here is my actual query:

```
SELECT CARE1.students.first_name, CARE1.students.grade, CARE1.students.id, 
CARE1.student_test_info.test_num, CARE1.student_test_info.date_of_testing,
0 as WI, 0 as SI, 0 as OC, 0 as SL 
FROM CARE1.students INNER JOIN CARE1.student_test_info ON CARE1.students.id = CARE1.student_test_info.student_id

WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.WI)
AND (id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.SI)
OR id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.OC))
```

Basically each of the tables (WI, SI, etc) have test info in them and we are trying to make sure everyone took all of the tests. The query works in giving me the list of people that missed a test, but doesn't tell me what tests they missed, that is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Oh, sorry, let me edit the post

Comment: and `table1` is useless?

Comment: My sample code may have not been completely right, tried to simplify my query for the sake of the site, I will post the actual query in a second. Basically I am saying it's in table1 and also in at least one of the other 2 tables, then I want to output which of those tables it is in

Comment: You should also explain what are `table1`, `table2` and `table3` aswell as how  they relate to `students` table.

Comment: New edit should explain, thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the WHERE conditions are correct - You can use the same conditions in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT
    CARE1.students.first_name,
    CARE1.students.grade,
    CARE1.students.id, 
    CARE1.student_test_info.test_num,
    CARE1.student_test_info.date_of_testing,
    id IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.WI) as WI, -- is always 1 due to WHERE condition
    id IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.SI) as SI,
    id IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.OC) as OC,
    0 as SL -- What is SL?
FROM CARE1.students
INNER JOIN CARE1.student_test_info
    ON CARE1.students.id = ARE1.student_test_info.student_id
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.WI)
  AND (id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.SI)
    OR id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT studentID from CARE1.OC))
```

However - I would suggest to use `EXISTS` subqueries instead of `IN`. And also use a HAVING clause with aliases of calculated colums to avoid code duplication:

```
SELECT
    CARE1.students.first_name,
    CARE1.students.grade,
    CARE1.students.id, 
    CARE1.student_test_info.test_num,
    CARE1.student_test_info.date_of_testing,
    1 as WI, -- is always 1 due to WHERE condition
    EXISTS (SELECT * from CARE1.SI WHERE CARE1.SI.studentID = CARE1.students.id) as SI,
    EXISTS (SELECT * from CARE1.OC WHERE CARE1.OC.studentID = CARE1.students.id) as OC,
    0 as SL -- What is SL?
FROM CARE1.students
INNER JOIN CARE1.student_test_info
    ON CARE1.students.id = ARE1.student_test_info.student_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * from CARE1.WI WHERE CARE1.WI.studentID = CARE1.students.id)
HAVING SI = 0
    OR OC = 0
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! Good to know that you can do that in the SELECT for next time I need this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, grade, id, 1 as WI, 0 as SI FROM students
WHERE id in table1
AND id in table2
UNION
SELECT name, grade, id, 0 as WI, 1 as SI FROM students
WHERE id in table1 AND
id in table3
```

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN to table1 to get ids that exist there only. LEFT JOIN to tables 2 & 3. Using a case statement will give you the flexibility to display any custom value based on this logic if you need anything other than 0 or 1...

```
SELECT name, 
        grade, 
        id, 
        CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WI --update with any value you want to display, 
        CASE WHEN t3.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as SI 
    FROM 
        students s INNER JOIN
        table1 t1 on s.id = t1.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
        table2 t2 on s.id = t2.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
        table3 t3 on s.id = t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.name, s.grade, s.id,
 MAX(t2.id IS NOT NULL) AS WI,
 MAX(t3.id IS NOT NULL) AS SI 
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON s.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
ON s.id = t3.id
GROUP BY s.id
```